# Can anyone help me to get the query to retrieve data like below

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    A                      B                   c

id   sal                 id  sal          id     sal
--------                 --------         -----------
1    100                  1  100           1     100
2    200                  2  200           2     200
3    300                  3  300           
4    400
```

Output should be:

```
id   sal
----------
1    300
2    600
3    600
4    400
```

Comment: It is great if you show what you have tried so far as often you can be closer than you realize and it helps others give you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query for the exact results you are looking for.

```
select 
    A.id, 
    sum(A.sal + ISNULL(B.sal, 0) + ISNULL(C.sal, 0) ) sal 
from TableA A
    left join TableB B 
        on A.id = B.id
    left join TableC C 
        on A.id = C.id
group by A.id
```

Also, in case TableC or TableB were to contain records that are not in the other tables, you can use the below code:

```
select 
    IsNULL(A.id, IsNULL(B.id, C.id)) as id, 
    sum(ISNULL(A.sal, 0) + ISNULL(B.sal, 0) + ISNULL(C.sal, 0) ) sal 
from TableA A
    full outer join TableB B 
        on A.id = B.id
    full outer join TableC C 
        on A.id = C.id
group by IsNULL(A.id,IsNULL(B.id,C.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    x.id as id, 
    sum(x.sal) as sal  
from (
    select id as id, sal as sal from A
    union all
    select id as id, sal as sal from B
    union all
    select id as id, sal as sal from C
    ) as x
group by x.id
```

Comment: thanks michael.but i need join with is null condition.

Comment: If only records from A should be found in result.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT A.ID,
       SUM(ISNULL(A.SAL,0)+ISNULL(B.SAL,0)+ISNULL(C.SAL,0)) TOTAL 
FROM A left JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID  
       left JOIN C ON B.ID=C.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```